# Massive spike in YouTube Data API queries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, heroku, youtube

I noticed I was hitting the 10,000 unit quota limit for the YouTube data api which doesn't seem right as I'm only pulling playlist videos for my app.
[Here's what I'm talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJYx2.png)

I checked the Google Developer's console and saw that my unit usage was going up, so I removed the app from heroku and got a new key, and it seems to have stopped. Here is the code using the API.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { gapi } from 'gapi-script';
import '../css/YouTube.css'
import {Animated} from "react-animated-css";
import Spinner from 'react-bootstrap/Spinner'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import { FiArrowUpCircle } from "react-icons/fi";

export default class YouTube extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            videos: [],
            loading: true
        };
        this.loadClient = this.loadClient.bind(this);
        this.execute = this.execute.bind(this);
        this.swap = this.swap.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount(){   
        gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
            gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "Placeholder client id"});
            }); 
        this.loadClient().then(this.execute).then((array) => {
            for (let i=0; i < array.length; i++){
                array[i] = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${array[i]}`;
            }
            this.setState({videos: array, loading: false})
        });        
    }

    swap(i1,i2){
        let tempVids = this.state.videos;
        let link1 = tempVids[i1],
        link2 = tempVids[i2];
        tempVids[i1] = link2;
        tempVids[i2] = link1;
        this.setState({videos: tempVids, loading: false})

    }

    loadClient(){
        gapi.client.setApiKey("old api key");
        return gapi.client.load("https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
        function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
    }

    execute(){
        return gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
            "part": [
                "snippet"
            ],
            "playlistId": "UUvgfXK4nTYKudb0rFR6noLA"
            })
                .then(function(response, array=[]) {
                        let videos = response.result.items;
                        for (let video of videos){
                            let id = video.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
                            array.push(id)
                        }
                        return array;
                    },
                    function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err);});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className='load'>
                    <>{this.state.loading ? <Spinner animation="border" role="status" variant='light'></Spinner> : <div></div>}</>
                </div>
                <Animated animationIn='fadeInLeft'>
                    <div class='videos'>
                            <iframe className='primary' title='0' width="70%" height="576" src={this.state.videos[0]} frameBorder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; 
                            encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowFullScreen></iframe>
                            <a rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" href='https://www.youtube.com/user/UFC/videos'><h2>More Videos</h2></a>
                            <hr></hr>
                            <div className='bottom'>
                                <div className='secondary'>
                                    <iframe className='primary' title='1' width="315" height="auto" src={this.state.videos[1]} frameBorder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; 
                                    encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowFullScreen></iframe>
                                    <Button onClick={this.swap.bind(this,0, 1)} variant="success"><FiArrowUpCircle size='2em'></FiArrowUpCircle></Button>{' '}
                               </div>
                               <div className='secondary'>
                                    <iframe className='primary' title='2' width="315" height="auto" src={this.state.videos[2]} frameBorder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; 
                                    encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowFullScreen></iframe>
                                    <Button onClick={this.swap.bind(this,0, 2)} variant="success"><FiArrowUpCircle size='2em'></FiArrowUpCircle></Button>{' '}
                               </div>
                               <div className='secondary'>
                                    <iframe className='primary' title='3' width="315" height="auto" src={this.state.videos[3]} frameBorder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; 
                                    encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowFullScreen></iframe>
                                    <Button onClick={this.swap.bind(this,0, 3)} variant="success"><FiArrowUpCircle size='2em'></FiArrowUpCircle></Button>{' '}
                               </div>
                               <div className='secondary'>
                                    <iframe className='primary' title='4' width="315" height="auto" src={this.state.videos[4]} frameBorder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; 
                                    encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowFullScreen></iframe>
                                    <Button onClick={this.swap.bind(this,0, 4)} variant="success"><FiArrowUpCircle size='2em'></FiArrowUpCircle></Button>{' '}
                               </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </Animated>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

However I'd rather these spikes didn't happen, how can I prevent these before using my new key and redeploying to heroku?

Comment: are you sure there is no logic anywhere that is unexpectedly hammering the API by accident? or many users?

Comment: It's a personal project so many users are out of the question. I'll take a look at the logic.

Comment: I learned that I really shouldn't be using API keys in the front end, I'll be moving API requests to a node server and see if the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hid all API stuff in a Node server and environment variables. I deployed the server to heroku and fetched from the server in the front end. This has fixed the problem.